# Devolver fecha como dd\MM\yyyy en oracle toad

Tags: oracle, select, toad

necesito una mano con un simple select de oracle toad.
Necesito hacer un select sysdate y que si o si me devuelva la fecha con este formato:
dd\\MM\\yyyy

dos días separado de meses con dos \, dos meses separados de años con dos \.

este select (me devuelve un solo mes) y separado de un solo slash, necesito dos backslashses:

`select to_date(to_char(sysdate,'dd/mm/yyyy'),'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual;`

result:
29/9/2022

esperado

29\\09\\20222

desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

lo pude resolver, por si alguien se encuentra con el mismo problema esta es la query

select to_char(SYSDATE, 'dd\\mm\\yyyy') from dual;